# How to use constraints on ranges with a junction table?

Tags: postgresql

Based on the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT) it's pretty straightforward how to prevent any overlapping reservations in the table at the same time.

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
CREATE TABLE room_reservation (
    room text,
    during tsrange,
    EXCLUDE USING GIST (room WITH =, during WITH &&)
);
```

However, when you have multiple resources that can be reserved by users, what is the best approach to check for overlappings? You can see below that I want to have users reserve multiple resources. That's why I'm using the junction table Resources_Reservations. Is there any way I can use EXCLUDE in order to check that no resources are reserved at the same time?

```sql
CREATE TABLE Users(
    id serial primary key,
    name text
);

CREATE TABLE Resources(
    id serial primary key,
    name text
);

CREATE TABLE Reservations(
    id serial primary key,
    duration tstzrange,
    user_id serial,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Resources_Reservations(
    resource_id serial,
    reservation_id serial,
    FOREIGN KEY (resource_id) REFERENCES Resources(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (reservation_id) REFERENCES Reservations(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (resource_id, reservation_id)
);
```

Comment: I cannot think of any way to accomplish this without duplicating the `duration` into Resources_Reservations because the GIST exclusion needs to have access to that column to check `(resource_id WITH =, duration WITH &&)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is doable with a slight model change.  
But first let's correct a misconception. You have foreign key columns (user_id, resource_id, etc) defined as SERIAL. This is incorrect, they should be INTEGER. This is because SERIAL is not actually a data type. It is a psuedo-data type that is actually a [shortcut for](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/): creating a sequence, creating a column of type integer, and defining the sequence created as the default value.  With that out of the way.  
I think your Resources_Reservations is redundant. A reservation is by a user, but a reservation without something reserved would just be user information. Bring the resource_id into Reservation. Now a Reservation is by a *user* for a *resource* with a *duration*. Everything your current model contains but less complexity.
Assuming you don't have data that needs saving, then:

```
create table users(
    id serial primary key,
    name text
);
     
create table resources(
    id serial primary key,
    name text
);
 
create table reservations(
    user_id     integer
    resource_id integer
    duration    tstzrange,
    foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
    foreign key (resource_id) references resources(id), 
    primary key (resource_id, user_id)    
);
```

You should now be able to create your GIST exclusion.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It is something I thought it myself but I didn't go for it because I lose the relationship of many-to-many i.e. a user can have a single reservation with many resources. With the updated model, the user must create as many reservations as the resources he wants to reserve. Either I go for it and make sure my application makes multiple reservations out from a single reservation request, either I write some functions/trigger to deal with the junction table (duplicating duration column in it), or I implement the logic in the application. I'm not sure which path I'll follow.